# Math in table doesn't work

Tags: tables, math-mode

I have a table, which code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
   \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{llc}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Cluster} & Logic expression\tnote{1}\\
    \midrule
1&High performer& $ F\land E\land P\land N $ \\
2&Cash provider& $ F\land E\land P\land \lneg N $ \\
3&AMF& $ F\land E\land \lneg P\land N $\\
4&Doubtful case& $(F\land E\land \lneg P\land \lneg N)\lor (\lneg F\land \lneg E\land P\land N)$ \\
5&Low performer& $\lneg E\land (\lneg F\lor \lneg N\lor P)(F\lor \lneg P)$ \\
6&Possible AMF& $E\land \lneg F\land \lneg P\land N$ \\
7&CFO& $E\land \lneg F\land (P\lor \lneg N)$ \\
8&SCF needy& $\lneg F\land E\land \lneg P\land N$ \\
9&Potential cash provider& $\lneg F\land \lneg E\land P\land \lneg N$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1] Convention: AND $\rightarrow \land$, OR $\rightarrow \lor$, negation $\rightarrow \lnot$.
   \end{tablenotes}
  \caption{Logic expressions for each cluster.}
  \label{boolean}%
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Now... It does not compile, giving me the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.20 2&Cash provider& $ F\land E\land P\land \lneg N $ \
```

I know more or less where the problem is (or at least I suppose to know): is like as latex looks at the equations as if they are written one after the other, like:

```
$ F\land E\land P\land N $
$ F\land E\land P\land \lneg N $
```

or something like that, and therefore returns an error when it sees the second `$...$`; the problem is that I don't have any idea on how to solve the issue...

- Changing `$...$` with `\(...\)` makes no difference;
- Changing `$...$` with `\begin{math}...\end{math}` makes no difference as well, the same as put a `\begin{math}` before the first equation and one `\end{math}` after the last (my desperate tentative :D );
- General purpose google searches didn't give relevant results (unfortunately).

I am quite sure it's something trivial... but I cannot understand what!

Comment: I get simply errors as `\lneg` is not defined. Check the definition of the symbol you want to use.

Comment: I think the macro you should be using (instead of the undefined `\lneg`) is called `\lnot`. If you use `\lnot`, the document compiles without an error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbol you're trying to typeset is called

```
\lnot
```